# NewRelic crash with infinite recursion

Tags: ios, recursion, crash, infinite-loop, newrelic

iOS frequently crashes with infinite recursion with following stack:

```
#7801   0x01c96241 in _writeJSONValue ()
#7802   0x01c9a660 in ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke ()
#7803   0x04bbad86 in __53-[__NSArrayM     enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke ()
#7804   0x04bbac92 in -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] ()
#7805   0x04b37ca5 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] ()
....
#7822   0x04bbac92 in -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] ()
#7823   0x04b37ca5 in -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] ()
#7824   0x01c9a571 in _writeJSONArray ()
#7825   0x01c96241 in _writeJSONValue ()
#7826   0x01c95f9d in -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] ()
#7827   0x01c98b57 in +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] ()
#7828   0x001a7ec8 in ptrIntPtrParamHandler at /Users/jenkins/workspace/iOS v3 Agent -
```

**EDIT, please look to the screen NewRelic generates the error, not mine code**
[image: Screen of stack]

Comment: Please check, the question, I've added screenshot with stack. Not my code generates recursion. Why my question was minus? It is still critical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an old bug with the agent (pre-v3.252). An update to the latest version of New Relic should fix this.